# Difference between Thread, Task and async/await keywords

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

Last days I try learning about Multitasking in .NET. I have few question about this.
First of all. I know that in .NET exist thing who's name is "ThreadPool", so if we create new thread with Thread class we using thread from ThreadPool or create new one?

What about Task library. In the msdn we can read: "Represents an asynchronous operation." but create new thread and using asynchronous are two different ways, right? So if we using Task library we create async operations or create new thread?

If yes so when we should to using async/await keywords? 
Where is the difference betweent above approach?

Comment: You're mixing two different concepts: Asynchronous programming and multitasking.

Comment: So maybe can you describe me it? Or give me any link where can I find compare.

Comment: Sorry, was writing from my phone.  It was more like *these are the things you should search for* advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets try and break each question:

> so if we create new thread with Thread class we using thread from
>   ThreadPool or create new one?

The `ThreadPool` does what its name indicates, it is a pool of threads. When you use the `Thread` class, you're creating a **new** Thread, unrelated to these that exist in the `ThreadPool`.

> In the msdn we can read: "Represents an asynchronous operation." but
>   create new thread and using asynchronous are two different ways,
>   right?

Right. Doing an asynchronous operation doesn't mean "create a new thread and work on that thread". I mean, that is doing things in *parallel*. Asynchronous operations usually [require no extra threads](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) in the process at all, they are naturally asynchronous all the way down to the OS.

> So if we using Task library we create async operations or create new
>   thread?

You can do both:

1. Promise-style tasks - These play along together nicely with the `async-await` operators introduced in C# 5. They represent asynchronous operations which require no threads to be used. An example of these can be found in various BCL classes, such a the `Stream` classes, `HttpClient`, etc. Notice that most of the classes doing I/O bound operations use promise style task.
2. Using `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`. This will take a `ThreadPool` thread and execute the provided delegate inside unless you explicitly tell it you want it to create a new Thread using `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`.

> If yes so when we should to using async/await keywords?

`async-await` goes along with anything that is an `awaitable`. An `awaitable` is any class/struct that has a `GetAwaiter` method, which return a type that implements `INotifyCompletion` or `ICriticalNotifyCompletion` interface. You can read more about `async-await` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: It's up to the `TaskFactory` how it invoked explicitly created tasks, asynchronously.  The most common way is to use the threadpool, but there are other types of task factories...  W

Comment: Also, it's best to use `await` *only* when you need to model one or more asynchronous operations sequentially that, when complete, need to return to a particular threading context.  Most of the time, this means when invoking asynchronous operations from a UI thread.

Comment: I wouldn't say "asynchronous operations require no threads", as their callbacks must occur on a thread, even if it's the original thread ;) But if you are using some kind of begin/wait or other type that calls a callback explicitly, then that happens on a thread as well.  But yes, the actual operation may not be running on a thread.

Comment: @Erik I ment the actual operation itself wont consume a thread. Of course it will have to invoke an IOCP once it completes. Note i said *extra* thread as well.